# Ubuntu 16.04 Systemd start up file?

Tags: 16.04

I added a command via the GUI to run on start up. Now I'm having issues logging in and I'd like to manually remove this command via the terminal (as xsession is having issues).

I've been trying to locate the file responsible for this but have had to luck in finding in. Does anyone know?

Comment: It depends on how you added the command. What command did you add and how/where did you add it?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I stated that I added the command via the Ubuntu Unity GUI.

Answer (score 0):

After logging in with Console navigate to the directory:

```
cd /home/your-user-name/.config/autostart/
```

Then list the `Startup Applications` scripts with `ls`. You should see your script there. Remove it with:

```
rm script-name
```

Then reboot.